# Desmarcar y Guardar checkbox de una ventana modal

Tags: javascript

Poseo un grupo de radiobutton:

1. ninguno:
2. Atenuantes
3. Agravantes

Al pulsarse la opcion 2 o 3, estos muestran una ventana modal con distintos checkbox generados desde una base de datos:

Funciones PHP

```
function listaAtenuantes()
      {
      global $conexion;
      global $conexion;
      $stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT id_aparte,desc_circunstancia FROM circunstancias WHERE id_articulo=40");
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->store_result();
      $stmt->bind_result($stmt1, $stmt2);
      while ($stmt->fetch())
            {
            echo "</br>" . "<input type='checkbox' onclick='validacionMaximo(this);' name='atenuantes[]' value='" . $stmt1 . "'>" . $stmt2;
            }
      $stmt->close();
      }

function listaAgravantes()
      {
      global $conexion;
      global $conexion;
      $stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT id_aparte,desc_circunstancia FROM circunstancias WHERE id_articulo=41");
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->store_result();
      $stmt->bind_result($stmt1, $stmt2);
      while ($stmt->fetch())
            {
            echo "</br>" . "<input type='checkbox'  onclick='validacionMaximo(this);' name='agravantes[]' value='" . $stmt1 . "'>" . $stmt2;
            }
      $stmt->close();
      }
```

Tengo tambien un grupo de input de texto donde se guardan la cantidad de checkbox que fueron marcados por tipo

1. Cantidad Atenuantes
2. Cantidad Agravantes

Quisiera que:

- Al pulsar ninguno se coloquen en cero las caja de texto de cantidad (lo tengo resuelto) y que las ventanas modales queden con sus checkbox desmarcados (**NO FUNCIONA**)
- Al pulsar un radiobutton se deshabiliten las opciones de marcar el otro radiobutton pues el valor del radiobutton se guardara (lo tengo)
- Al pulsar ninguno se quite el estado disabled de las opciones 2 y 3 que fue generado al pulsar el radio en un primer momento (lo tengo)
- Funcion que limite los checkbox a 2 (lo tengo)

**El problema:** la funcion js de borrar no me desmarca los checkbox por lo tanto cuando marco ninguno y habilito las opciones 2 y 3 estas continuan teniendo los checkbox marcados y si la persona cambio de opinion de atenuante a agravante no podra marcarlos pues tiene la funcion de limite.

**Como puedo resolverlo?**

Aqui los codigos:

**Codigo JS de borrar** (funciona sin usar ventanas modales):

```
function borrar(){
var cf = document.getElementsByName('atenuantes');
var cs = document.getElementsByName('agravantes');

for (i=0; i<cf.length; i++){
if(cf[i].checked = true){
cf[i].checked = false;
}
}

for (i=0; i<cs.length; i++){
if(cs[i].checked = true){
cs[i].checked = false;
}
}
}
```

**Codigo HTML ventanas y Radiobutton**

```
 <tr id="tipo_circunstancia">
   <td>Seleccione el tipo de circunstancia influyente: </td>
   <td>
   <input type="radio" name="tipo_circunstancia" id="ninguno"              onclick="vaciar();" value ="0" checked > Ninguno 
   <input type="radio" name="tipo_circunstancia" id="tipo_atenuante"       onclick="window.location='#popup1';toggle(this); borrar()"  href="#popup1" value="1"> Atenuantes 
   <input type="radio" name="tipo_circunstancia" id="tipo_agravante"   onclick="window.location='#popup2';toggle(this); borrar()"  value="2"> Agravantes
   </td>
   <td>Datos de Circunstancias: </td>
   <td colspan="1" align="center">
   Atenuantes:  <input type="text" size="2" value="0" id="cantidad1" disabled>
   Agravantes:  <input type="text" size="2" value="0" id="cantidad2" disabled>
   </td>
   </tr>

    <div class="modal-wrapper" id="popup1">
    <div class="popup-contenedor">
    <h2>Circunstancias Atenuantes</h2>
    <?php
    listaAtenuantes();
    ?>
    <a class="popup-cerrar" onclick="verificar();deshabilitar();focus();" href="#">ACEPTAR</a>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-wrapper" id="popup2">
    <div class="popup-contenedor">
    <h2>Circunstancias Agravantes</h2>
    <?php
    listaAgravantes();
    ?>
    <a class="popup-cerrar" onclick="verificar();deshabilitar();" href="#">ACEPTAR</a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**Link del CSS para las ventanas**: http://soyfrontend.com/crear-ventana-modal-con-solo-css/ (mucho texto)

Comment: Algun Moderador que lea esto:

En el caso de la pregunta, obtuve la respuesta pero es algo muy sencillo, deberia eliminarla o autoresponderla?

Disculpen que lo haga asi

Comment: Tu puedes autoresponderla

Comment: Si has encontrado la solucion a tu pregunta, claro que puedes autoresponderla, eso contrubuye al crecimiento del sitio

Comment: Puedes autoresponderla siempre y cuando aporte algo; si el problema era por cuestiones de sintaxis o similar, es mejor eliminarla porque no fue un "problema" como tal.

Comment: fue que unicamente cambie el valor dentro del js de borrar, antes tenia los corchetes de array, pero me dijeron que eso estaba mal y cuando probe el script hoy no sirvio, tengo anotado los cambio, lo regreso y funciono, lo publico?. como hago cuando quiera que un moderador revise la pregunta sin hacer lo del titulo? jejeje de una manera mas formal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hace poco en otra pregunta me sugirieron cambiar el modo de validar los checkbox y me decian que borrara los [] corchetes del document.getElement, esto ocasiono que no se guardaran pues ellos hacen que el codigo identifique que son un arreglo.

Aqui la solución

```
function borrar(){
var cf = document.getElementsByName('atenuantes[]');
var cs = document.getElementsByName('agravantes[]');

for (i=0; i<cf.length; i++){
if(cf[i].checked = true){
cf[i].checked = false;
}
}

for (i=0; i<cs.length; i++){
if(cs[i].checked = true){
cs[i].checked = false;
}
}
}
```